# javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! is being thrown, but I don't know why it is?

Tags: java

I wanted to learn how to make 3d graphics in java and found this code and study it and looked on how it worked and I searched how each command works. I ran the code and it gives me an error I don't really understand how its not working. Its suppose to place the textures on the walls in the map but won't place them. I am using eclipse to run the code.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {
    public int[] pixels;
    private String loc;
    public final int SIZE;
        public Texture(String location, int size) {
        loc = location;
        SIZE = size;
        pixels = new int[SIZE * SIZE];
        load();
    }

    private void load() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(loc));
            int w = image.getWidth();
            int h = image.getHeight();
            image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Texture wood = new Texture("res/wood.png", 64);
    public static Texture brick = new Texture("res/redbrick.png", 64);
    public static Texture bluestone = new Texture("res/bluestone.png", 64);
    public static Texture stone = new Texture("res/greystone.png", 64);
}






import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int mapWidth = 15;
    public int mapHeight = 15;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private BufferedImage image;
    public int[] pixels;
    public ArrayList<Texture> textures;
    public Camera camera;
    public Screen screen;
    public static int[][] map = 
        {
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,0,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2},
            {1,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,0,3,3,0,3,3,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,0,4,4,4},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,3,3,3,3,0,4},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,3,3,3,3,0,4},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
        };

    public Game() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        image = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        textures = new ArrayList<Texture>();
        textures.add(Texture.wood);
        textures.add(Texture.brick);
        textures.add(Texture.bluestone);
        textures.add(Texture.stone);
        camera = new Camera(4.5, 4.5, 1, 0, 0, -.66);
        screen = new Screen(map, mapWidth, mapHeight, textures, 1920, 1080);
        addKeyListener(camera);
        setSize(1920, 1080);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("3D Engine");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        start();
    }
    private synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        bs.show();
    }
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;//60 times per second
        double delta = 0;
        requestFocus();
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta = delta + ((now-lastTime) / ns);
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1)//Make sure update is only happening 60 times a second
            {
                //handles all of the logic restricted time
                screen.update(camera, pixels);
                camera.update(map);
                delta--;
            }
            render();//displays to the screen unrestricted time
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

This is the error message I been getting every time I run the code. I have tried using different locations for the textures but keep getting the same error message.

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at Texture.load(Texture.java:20)
    at Texture.<init>(Texture.java:15)
    at Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:29)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
    at Game.main(Game.java:104)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at Texture.load(Texture.java:20)
    at Texture.<init>(Texture.java:15)
    at Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:30)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
    at Game.main(Game.java:104)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at Texture.load(Texture.java:20)
    at Texture.<init>(Texture.java:15)
    at Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:31)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
    at Game.main(Game.java:104)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at Texture.load(Texture.java:20)
    at Texture.<init>(Texture.java:15)
    at Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:32)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
    at Game.main(Game.java:104)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is self-explanatory: res/* files cannot be read.

Assuming you already have a res folder including these files, that folder should be in classpath. If not put it in classpath or change res/* into absolute path, e.g. C:\res\wood.png

The exception is thrown on javax.imageio.ImageIO:

```
public static BufferedImage read(File input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
        }
        if (!input.canRead()) {
            throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");
        }
```

The File.canRead() is (on openJdk 1.8.0_192)

```
 public boolean canRead() {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkRead(path);
        }
        if (isInvalid()) {
            return false;
        }
        return fs.checkAccess(this, FileSystem.ACCESS_READ);
    }
```

The input.canRead() returns false only if the path is invalid or the path or file does not have read access. If you use an absolute path in Linux, check that the user has read access in the path recursively

Comment: @3dog It would appear your image files are _resources_. Never try to access resources via the `File` class. You should be using `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead. Make sure you use the correct path as well—see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).